# Does anyone know why Take() isn't working here

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, take

i have the following code using Nhibernate.Linq

```
   var apps = Session.Linq<History>().OrderByDescending(r => r.LastUpdated).Take(50);
   Console.Write(apps.Count());
```

the count returns 1000 (NOT 50 which is what i would have expected)

any ideas why the .Take() is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the Linq provider (you are using the old one, I tried the new one too and it still doesn't work).

You should open an issue in http://jira.nhforge.org/

As a workaround, use `.ToList()` in the assignment to apps.

Comment: You should either attach the classes and mappings, or use some of the existing ones in the test project, and create a proper unit test that fails. Look at the examples in the source code.